# Programmatically create Rich Text File in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have alot of text inputs in my application, and I want to create a rich text file with them. Something like this:

- **Favorites**

  - Apples
  - Oranges
  - *Banannas*

But I need it to be a file I can email, like .rtf, .doc, or something else widely used. I could either build the file on the fly, or have a template in my bundle and do "find-and-replace" for key-value pairs. But I'm not sure how to do either, or of there is an easier way all together. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is HTML format enough for that? You can that and send an html email.